# Internal compiler error: java.lang.NullPointerException at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.problem.ProblemHandler.handle(ProblemHandler.java:148)

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, eclipse-jee

I just imported a Java EE project that I made about a year ago. But after I imported it, i get this error in the first line of one of the files:

```
Internal compiler error: java.lang.NullPointerException at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.problem.ProblemHandler.handle(ProblemHandler.java:148)
```

[image: error in first line of file]

I am able to run the project on the server but it doesn't work, the website won't show up.

I tried removing the first line but I still get the same error.

I also get the same error during building.

There is no other error in the code, I can't post the entire code because it's around 3000 lines long.

Here is the project hierarchy:

[image: project hierarchy]

Comment: It looks like eclipse specific error. Probably change eclipse version or use some other IDE. IntelliJ has a free community version for java. For server error, please share stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and it turns out I was using lombok 1.18.18 and this version has a known issue:
https://github.com/projectlombok/lombok/issues/2752

Answer (score 0):

This is an Eclipse Bug.
http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/#4.8_Integration_Builds (Use newer than 2018-06-16).

Check your eclipse version in the above comment link and the NPE Should be gone.